# How to write mapper(MapStruct) from a list type to a list

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

We have a class representing Animal transfering attribute value to WildAnimal.Both types are rather similar, only the attributes have different names and the type attribute is same.

```
public class Animal{
    private List<Cat> cats;
}

public class Cat {
    private String colour;
    private Integer weight;
}

public class WildAnimal{

    private List<WildCat> wildCats;
}
public class WildCat {
    private String shade;
    private Integer mass;
}

@Mapper
public interface AnimalMapper {
  @Mapping( source = "cats", target = "wildCats")

  WildAnimal animalTowildAnimal(Animal animal);
}
```

This is not working. Could you please tell me the correct way of doing it.
Thank you in adavance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the mapping instructions for the other types that are relevant for your "parent"-mapping operation.

Example:

```
@Mapper
public interface AnimalMapper {

  @Mapping(source = "colour", target = "shade")
  @Mapping(source = "weight", target = "mass")
  WildCat catToWildCat(Cat cat);

  @Mapping(source = "cats", target = "wildCats")
  WildAnimal animalToWildAnimal(Animal animal);
}
```

Comment: The catsToWildCats isn't important, but the rest are. Otherwise MapStruct does implicit mapping

Comment: @Filip yes you are correct. Updated the answer